# How to rename only second sheet in a spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I create a script to rename the second sheet in a workbook no matter what the current sheet name is?

I have a script that deletes all of the sheets except for the 1st and 2nd one.

Then I want to rename the second sheet with today's date. I have everything else except renaming.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var tz = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), tz, 'MM-dd-yyyy');
  sheets[1].setName(date);  // Rename second
}
```

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_sheet)